# How to add char to beginning of char[] which is safer than memove

Tags: arrays, c, char

I implemented how to add and remove a single char from the start of a char array by doing

```c
// add char 1 to start of buf
memmove(buf_t + 1, buf_t, msgLen_t);
buf_t[0] = '1';
msgLen_t++;

//removing the first char of buf
memmove(buf_s, buf_s + 1, strlen(buf_s + 1) + 1);
msgLen_s--;
```

but reading the docs there is unexpected behavior when arrays overlap which is happening in my program and corrupting a different buf array.

What is a safe way to add a char to the start of a char array and remove it? Thanks for any help you can give me.

Comment: What's `buf_t` declared as? Can you post a full [mcve]?

Comment: What do you mean by "when arrays overlap"?

Comment: are these strings or char arrays?  In the first case you use msgLen, suggesting arrays, while in the second you use strlen suggesting strings.

Comment: Im not too sure in c, I thought that there are no strings on char arrays, but they are declared like char buf_1[1024];

Comment: If you declared the array as `buf_t[1024]`, then you need to make sure that `msgLen_t` is **less than 1024** before calling `memmove`. Otherwise, you'll write a byte past the end of the array. And there's no problem using `memmove` with overlapping source and destination. That's what it's designed to do. It's `memcpy` that's not supposed to be used with overlapping source and destination.

Comment: btw: `strlen(buf_s + 1) + 1` is the same as `strlen(buf_s)` except for an empty string. With an empty string `strlen(buf_s + 1) + 1` is invalid. Also, with an empty string, you shouldn't call `memmove`, because there's nothing to move.